# Dúvida sobre POST e GET em php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5

Tentei pesquisar na internet, mas não consegui satisfazer a minha dúvida... 
Comecei a programar web recentemente, embora já tenha usado post e get, me deparei em uma situação aonde fiquei "empacado". Tenho a página cadastrar_endereco.php , que nada mais é do que um formulário com campos de textos para rua, bairro, cep e etc...
 Só que esse formulário possui 2 botões, o Buscar cep, que abre buscar_cep.php que busca o cep que o usuário digitou e salva em sessions, e retorna a cadastrar_endereco.php com os outros campos já preenchidos, mas tem também o botão salvar, que envia os valores digitados para dentro do BD... O problema é que, o campo CEP está em um , método POST, para o buscar_cep.php, enquanto os outros campos estão no  salvar.php Também via post, logo eu não consigo salvar o CEP no BD..... Me pergunto, se teria como eu colocar tudo em um , ou enviar o cep via get para o busca_cep.php, já que é uma informação pequena e que não necessita privacidade...

Comment: Posta seu código ou parte dele para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Seria mais simples por a funcionalidade da busca e do salvar no mesmo PHP. Aí, dependendo do botão de submit pressionado, você escolhe o procedimento a tomar.

Comment: O GET é utilizado para enviar parâmetros através da url, e podem ser recuperados, através do $_REQUEST['_param']; ou $_GET['_param']; por exemplo: <a href="aquilo.php?p=_param">LINK</a> pode ser recuperado no ficheiro aquilo.php utilizando print_r($_GET['_param']) ou $_REQUEST['_param'];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma possível solução seria usar esta estrutura:

```
Página PHP com o formulário 
|
+- If cliente clicou em "buscar cep"
|  |
|  +- Include "buscacep.php"
|     Que busca o endereço do cep e substitui as variáveis pegas com POST
|     Continua normalmente até mostrar o form
|
+- Else If cliente clicou em "enviar"
|  |
|  +- Include "salvanodb.php"
|     Que verifica se está tudo em ordem.
|     |
|     +- Se estiver, salva, redireciona para página de sucesso ( e die(); )
|     |
|     +- Se estiver faltando algo, guarda mensagem de erro em uma variável.
|        Nesse caso, nada de die(); que é pra continuar no form
|
+- Mostra o formulário, com os valores anteriormente digitados no value="" dos inputs
```

Comment: Os puristas do "Só pode MVC" vão adorar essa resposta :D